# I'm trying to debug STM32F446 board from virtual box(UBUNTU, hostos = windows10) , using openocd

Tags: stm32, libusb, openocd

My board STM32F446 is having a on-chip debugger(STLINK v2) and I'm trying to debug my executable from Linux environment i.e. (Virtual Box = Ubuntu, host os = windows 10).
I'm not able 
1. To see stlink debugger in the USB devices list , i.e. `lsusb` is not showing any stlink device.
   Though I did install stlink tools in Linux and updated `udev` rules
2. Not able see `openocd` interacting with STM32 board, I guess #1 is the root cause for this.

**output of lsusb**

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

so my question is "with ubuntu running on virtual box would be able to identify STLINK debugger" ?

Comment: maybe you can find something helpful here: https://superuser.com/questions/1406699/issue-with-usb-device-and-virtualbox

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to see STlink from ubuntu running on a virtual machine before. Are you sharing your USBs with your virtual machine?
(I haven't used virtual box. I used VMWare on a Mac), but most users forgot to enable USB sharing.